# Absolute path with IMG_RESOURCE

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm looking for a way to get an absolute path for an IMG_RESOURCE object in TypoScript. Since baseUrl is no real solution to me, simply add `config.baseUrl = example.com` isn't the thing I am accepting.

So, how could I solve something like this:

```
ogimage = FILES
ogimage{
    references {
        table = pages
        uid.data = page:uid
        fieldName = tx_csseo_og_image
    }
    renderObj = IMG_RESOURCE
    renderObj {
        file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
        file.height < plugin.tx_csseo.social.openGraph.image.height
        file.width < plugin.tx_csseo.social.openGraph.image.width
        # this needs to be generated with an absolute URL
        stdWrap.dataWrap = <meta property="og:image" content="|" />
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got a solution by myself. The point of the question was to not set the domain at any point at all. And have an absolute URL rendered from the FILES and IMG_RESOURCE objects, to be able to resize the image.

```
ogimage = FILES
ogimage{
    references {
        table = pages
        uid.data = page:uid
        fieldName = tx_csseo_og_image
    }
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj {
        typolink{
            parameter.stdWrap{
                cObject = IMG_RESOURCE
                cObject{
                    file.import.data = file:current:uid
                    file.treatIdAsReference = 1
                    file.height < plugin.tx_csseo.social.openGraph.image.height
                    file.width < plugin.tx_csseo.social.openGraph.image.width
                }
            }
            returnLast = url
            forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
        }
        wrap = <meta property="og:image" content="|" />
    }
}
```

This will generate a resized image via IMG_RESOURCE and then generate an absolute url to this generated image via typolink, that will be then wrapped inside a meta-tag.

Answer (score 2):

You might need something like this:

```
ogimage = FILES
ogimage {
   //get the image url from the seo field
  references {
     table = pages
     uid.data = page:uid
     fieldName = tx_csseo_og_image
  }
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {
    10 = TEXT
    10.data = DB:sys_domain:1:domainName
    10.wrap = |
    20 = TEXT
    20.data = file:current:publicUrl
    20.wrap = /|
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the approach is the right one! However using `DB:sys_domain:1:domainName` feels "hardcoded" to me. It's not flexible enough if your TYPO3 instance runs in different environments (staging, Testing, ...).

Answer (score 1):

## A more complete TypoScript-Only example could be my following example snippet

It renders following meta tags right within `page.meta` without the need to use `page.headerData.`:

- `og:image`
- `og:image:width`
- `og:image:height`
- `og:image:type`

### TypoScript Setup:

```
page {
    meta {
        og:image {
            attribute = property
            stdWrap.cObject = FILES
            stdWrap.cObject {
                references {
                    table = pages
                    uid.data = uid
                    fieldName = tx_theme_facebook_image
                }
                begin = 0
                maxItems = 1
                renderObj = TEXT
                renderObj {
                    stdWrap.typolink {
                        parameter.stdWrap {
                            cObject = IMG_RESOURCE
                            cObject {
                                file {
                                    crop.data = file:current:crop
                                    cropVariant = facebook_variant1
                                    import.data = file:current:uid
                                    treatIdAsReference = 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        returnLast = url
                        forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
                    }
                    required = 1
                }
            }
        }
        og:image:width {
            attribute = property
            stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
            stdWrap.cObject {
                data = TSFE:lastImgResourceInfo|0
            }
            stdWrap.if.isTrue.field = tx_theme_facebook_image
        }
        og:image:height {
            attribute = property
            stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
            stdWrap.cObject {
                data = TSFE:lastImgResourceInfo|1
            }
            stdWrap.if.isTrue.field = tx_theme_facebook_image
        }
        og:image:type {
            attribute = property
            stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
            stdWrap.cObject {
                data = TSFE:lastImgResourceInfo|2
                stdWrap.wrap = image/|
                required = 1
            }
            stdWrap.if.isTrue.field = tx_theme_facebook_image
        }
    }
}
```

### Some side note

This snippet is limited to image FAL relations (IRRE). File extension limitation must be configured right within your TCA configuration for your field/column (in this example `pages.tx_theme_facebook_image`). Even the amount of max items must be limited within TCA configuration.

### Multiple og:/twitter:image tags

And maybe it's a better idea to not use such a TypoScript-Only-Solution if you want to allow multiple og:image tags. The reason is that `og:image:width`/`og:image:height` meta tag must follow the og:image meta tag. If you still want to accomplish multiple `og:image` tags it would be a better idea to use `page.headerData` in conjunction with `FLUIDTEMPLATE` (as long as you want to use TypoScript).

---

**PS:** I heard about plans to implement basic SEO fields in TYPO3 CMS v9 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your problem. what do you want to achieve?

do you look for something like `config.absRefPrefix`?

anyway you don't should use

```
file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
```

try to use

```
    file {
        import.data = file:current:uid
        treatIdAsReference = 1
        :
```

Comment: The problem is, that such an `og:image` or `twitter:image` meta tag needs an absolute url to the final (processed (due resizing/cropping)) image resource. I think such a behaviour could only be realized by TypoScript by wrapping IMG_RESOURCE into typolink which generates absolute to the generated IMG_RESOURCE

Answer (score 0):

For me, a solution for og:image with inheritance was important. "tx_myext_ogimage" is a field in table pages.

```
10 = IMG_RESOURCE
10 {
    stdWrap.wrap = <meta property="og:image" content="{getIndpEnv:TYPO3_SITE_URL}|" />
    stdWrap.insertData = 1
    stdWrap.required = 1
    file {
        import.data = levelfield:-1, tx_myext_ogimage, slide
        treatIdAsReference = 1
        import.listNum = 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `levelmedia:-1, slide` for TYPO3 9.5 or newer.

[Doc](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-seo/master/en-us/Configuration/Index.html#setting-fallbacks-for-og-image-and-twitter-image) TYPO3 SEO Core extension

```
page.meta {  
        og:image.stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
        og:image.stdWrap.cObject {
            if.isFalse.field = og_image
            stdWrap.typolink {
                parameter.stdWrap.cObject = FILES
                parameter.stdWrap.cObject {
                    references {
                        data = levelmedia:-1, slide
                    }
                    renderObj = IMG_RESOURCE
                    renderObj {
                        file {
                            import.data = file:current:publicUrl
                            crop.data = file:current:crop
                            width = 1200c
                            height = 630c
                        }
                    }
                }
                returnLast = url
                forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
            }
        }
    }
```